# How to make App Engine use Cloud Build substitute variables for environmental variables?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I am trying to add Cloud Build on top of my App Engine Flask app. Everything works, but for some reason, I can't access the substitution variables I declared in the trigger.
Env vars are still being fetched from app.yaml. And they are parsed literally, not as variables. When I remove it from app.yaml Python throws a NoneType error.

[Trigger][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii6Jv.png

[App.yaml][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg646.png

```
runtime: python310
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
max_instances: 8
env_variables:
  _CONFIG_TYPE: ${_CONFIG_TYPE}
```

[cloudbuild][3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo0PN.png

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy']

timeout: '1600s'
substitutions:
  _CONFIG_TYPE: ${_CONFIG_TYPE}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because `gcloud app deploy` command start a new Cloud Build, behind the scene, to build a container with your code and to deploy it. Your env var will change anything

The solution is to perform a bash replacement, with sed for instance.

app.yaml file

```
runtime: python310
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
max_instances: 8
env_variables:
  _CONFIG_TYPE: ##_CONFIG_TYPE##
```

Cloud Build Step with env var usage

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  env-vars:
   - CONFIG_TYPE: ${_CONFIG_TYPE}
  args: 
   - '-c'
   - |
      sed -i "s/##_CONFIG_TYPE##/$${CONFIG_TYPE}/g" app.yaml
      gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600
      gcloud app deploy

timeout: '1600s'
substitutions:
  _CONFIG_TYPE: ${_CONFIG_TYPE}
```

Cloud Build Step without env var usage

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
   - '-c'
   - |
      sed -i "s/##_CONFIG_TYPE##/${_CONFIG_TYPE}/g" app.yaml
      gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600
      gcloud app deploy

timeout: '1600s'
substitutions:
  _CONFIG_TYPE: ${_CONFIG_TYPE}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked out almost perfect! One remark for others, if you try to substitute variables (like urls) that already contain forward slashes "/" this won't work, you have to change the delimiter to something else, like "|", for example `sed -i "s|##_CONFIG_TYPE##|${_CONFIG_TYPE}|g" app.yaml`
I was about to give up before I accidentally caught this in the logs: `sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to \`s'`. Thanks for the great answer!